# Phone keeps consuming cellular data plan instead of wifi

Tags: ios, network, wifi, cellular-data

Ever since upgrading to iOS14 a couple of months ago, there's been a big problem with our data consumption.  My wife and I have identical iPhone SEs (first edition) both on the latest iOS 14 now.  We are on a 1-gig per month data plan with Xfinity Mobile since we barely ever leave the house (and this has been the case for many many years, well before the pandemic), and we never go over the limit.  We usually don't even hit half that as we're on wifi nearly all the time.

But now, on 3 different occasions we have somehow mysteriously gone over the 1gig limit and been charged additional fees because of this.  Xfinity Mobile of course can't (won't) give us any specifics, they will only show the amount of data consumed per phone for the month.  No daily breakdown, no application-type breakdown, etc.  Getting support on the phone was no help, as they also could not give any additional detail.

This has literally never happened in the years we've been on Xfinity Mobile with these phones.  Then suddenly, immediately after updating to iOS14, it began and has now happened 4 times.  Twice in a single month even (meaning we somehow consumed over 3 gigs that month).  I have no reasonable explanation for this.  Our phones are connected to our home wifi network the same as they have always been.  It is set to auto-join and is the only network set as such.  We don't watch netflix or whatever on our phones.  She does sometimes consume Youtube content on hers.  But again we're on wifi so much that we haven't consumed even 1gig of cellular data in any month, in years.

I have now gone in on my phone and disabled cellular data for the apps that had consumed the most according to my phone (Music, Podcasts and App Store).  But in my wife's case the only app that consumes and particular amount of data is safari as she mostly browses the web.  I don't want to disable safari or she won't ever be able to look up anything real quick if we're grocery shopping, for example.

This is infuriating and I can't get any insights from Xfinity about the issue such as times of consumption, apps consuming the data, locations of consumption, etc.  The one thing I have caught a couple of times on her phone in specific, was that she was for some strange reason connected to "xfinitywifi" or "XFINITY", the former being the publicly-accessible free hotspot network Xfinity provides, and the latter being... I'm not sure what, but from my web searching is also an Xfinity-provided network.  Why she was suddenly connected to those networks she has never used before instead of our home network which was present and available, I have no idea.  I don't even know that this is connected to the cellular issue, but it's the only thing that stands out.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening since upgrading to iOS14?  That's the one common denominator I can see here.  So far this has happened twice due to her phone, and twice due to mine, in the last 3 months.

Comment: Have you checked if your(and your wife's) Wi-fi Assist is set off? It's under the cellular settings that's located in iOS' setting app.

Comment: Good idea, but it was off for me and on for her, and this has happened on both of our phones.  Was WiFi assist a new feature in iOS 14?  Because that’s exactly when this started happening- after we both upgraded.

Comment: As far as I remember, it's been there since iOS 9 or 10. I was curious because many people reported that this setting was forced to be turned on when updating to iOS14. I honestly can't think of anything else.

Comment: Another possibility is that there is something wrong with the Wi-fi router itself. Have you experienced Wi-Fi interruptions or bad connections on other devices?

Comment: Nope nothing like that at all.  And again this started immediately after upgrading to iOS 14, never before.  Doesn't feel like a mere coincidence.  I've spoken to Apple about this a couple weeks ago now, and they are attempting to get information from Comcast but so far, nothing.